# FQL does not return all news feeds

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using FQL to retrieve all of my news feeds (recent 50 or 30-days according to the documentation ). However, i am getting back only few feeds and not everything for the past 30 days. Does any one have the same issue? 
Here is the FQL i use to retrieve FEEDS:

```
SELECT created_time, updated_time, message, attachment, likes, share_count FROM stream WHERE filter_key in "
   @"( SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me() ) AND created_time <= now()
```

Also, i read that Graph API returns more results than FQL. I read few Graph API examples, but don't understand how my query should look if i want to list just photos posted on my news feed?

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with the easy one:

To return only posts that are photos, add `AND type = 247` to the `WHERE` section of your query. This is something you can't do with the Graph API.

For the other questions you have, the `stream` table is one of the most difficult to query and get the results you want.

For not getting enough results, the Facebook internal limits don't work as advertised in my experience. If you explicitly request a number of posts, by adding `LIMIT 100` to the end of your query, you usually can get close to the actual number of items you are expecting.

The Facebook filtering algorithms work on your results *after* the query executes, so you may end up with far fewer posts than you can see on your newsfeed within the Facebook web app. This has to do with privacy settings your friends may have enabled. And no, there isn't any way to test for these.

See [this Facebook dev blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/) for more details.